# Xquery Json display wrong values

Tags: json, rest, web-services, xpath, xquery

I am extracting data from a REST JSON web service, the ws response is:

```
{"Quanity":17,"Total":177331.105021}
```

The issue is with the values. The values are rounded

```
{"Quanity":17,"Total":177331}
```

I am using a third party app to connect to the ws (the data is displayed in a BI platform), I can connect and retrieve the data.

The code generate for the app to connect and retrieve the data is:

```
let $uri := ('http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
let $payload := ( )
let $jsonresult := mstr-rest:post($uri,$payload,$header)
let $result := json:parse($jsonresult)

return 
<Table><ColumnHeaders>
<ColumnHeader  name='json' type='xs:string' />
<ColumnHeader  name='Quantity' type='xs:number' />
<ColumnHeader  name='Total' type='xs:number' />
</ColumnHeaders>
<Data>{for $ancestor in $result
let $Quantity := $ancestor/pair
let $Total := $ancestor/pair
order by $ancestor
return <Row>
<json>{fn:data($ancestor)}</json>
<Quantity>{fn:data($Quantity[@name="Quantity"])}</Quantity>
<Total>{fn:data($Total[@name="Total"])}</Total>
</Row>}</Data></Table>
```

How can show the value with decimal places?

Comment: Is this using BaseX?

Comment: @MadsHansen I am not sure, the code is generated from a third party software and no indication what Xquery version or what Xquey processor is using.

Comment: But you are executing the XQuery code, right? Or you mean you are using some service that executes that XQuery and have no idea what it is under the covers?

Comment: In order to test whether it is the engine parsing that decimal as an integer or if it's being displayed different, try changing that ColumnHeader from xs:number to xs:string: `<ColumnHeader  name='Total' type='xs:string' />`

Comment: Also, could try removing the `fn:data()` and see if it's the atomization that is messing with it: `<Total>{$Total[@name="Total"]}</Total>`

Comment: @MadsHansen indeed, This code is generated in a third party app(and no documentation), the issue is I need to generate the code using the app,because is the only way the BI platform will let consume the ws. For that reason I post this question.